# Fractional Laplacian on the torus

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the Laplacian on the $n$ dimensional torus $T$, given by $-\Delta : L^2 \rightarrow L^2$. Let the domain of $-\Delta$ be all $C^\infty$ functions initially. Now consider the Friedrichs extension of $-\Delta$, still called $-\Delta$. I want to find explicitly what the domain of $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ is. Intuitively it seems to me that it should be all $L^2$ functions $u$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} u \in L^2, k = 1, 2,...,n$, but cannot prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit:** After Michael Renardy's comment:

Instead of $-\Delta$, let's say, we consider the following operator $-A = \sum^n_{i = 1} X_i^2$, where $X_i$ are vector fields generating the tangent space at each point, and $A \geq 0$, symmetric and densely defined on $L^2$, so that we can use the Friedrich's extension on $A$. Can we still say that the domain of $A^{1/2}$ consists exactly of all $L^2$ functions $u$ such that $X_i u \in L^2$ for all $i$? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Fourier series are your friend. But this is hardly a research level question.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Thanks for your comment. I also edited the question a bit for a little additional clarification.